# Can't see newline when echoing in textarea

Tags: php, html, textarea

hello i got the same problem as

[php :: new line in textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911261/php-new-line-in-textarea)

**or heres the error. ( no newlines )**

[image]

but it seems its not answered well in the above link.

`the var_dump($post['content']);` shows me

or something like

```
<pre dir="ltr" class="xdebug-var-dump"><small>string</small> <font color="#cc0000">'Duis libero sapien, cursus id tempus a, sollicitudin at urna. Maecenas elementum molestie massa quis pharetra. Donec eu libero ipsum. Aenean laoreet, tellus at pretium porta, nisl massa sodales massa, non laoreet sapien velit a neque. Praesent eleifend urna et diam sollicitudin eget pretium quam viverra. Sed rutrum enim quis lectus volutpat eleifend.





Nam in augue at diam tempus feugiat ac eu orci. Morbi pellentesque consequat lacinia. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesqu'...</font> <i>(length=634)</i></pre>
```

or

[image]

heres how i out put it.

```
<textarea name="content" cols="100" rows="50"><?php echo $post['content']; ?></textarea>
```

**heres what it should look like**

[image]

thanks for looking in.

Adam Ramadhan

**edit**

i am very sorry for the problem. the problem is yes im compressing each output from the views,

heres the function

```
public function compressor( $buffer )
{
    $search = array(
        '/(\s)+/s', // shorten multiple whitespace sequences <- THE MAIN PROBLEM
        '/<!--(.|\s)*?-->/', //strip html comments
        '/\>[^\S ]+/s', //strip whitespaces after tags, except space
        '/[^\S ]+\</s', //strip whitespaces before tags, except space
    );
    $replace = array(
        '\\1',
        '',
        '>',
        '<'
    );

    $buffer = preg_replace($search, $replace, $buffer); 
    return $buffer;
}
```

heres how i output my views

```
protected function view($view, $data = NULL)
{
    require_once 'libraries/core.views.php';
    $views = new Views;
    if ( config('compress') ) {

        /* See @ref #1 
        we are useing compressor just becouse ob_gzhandler dont support UTF-8 at the
        header, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php#91963
        */
        ob_start(array($this,'compressor'));
        # ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
    }

    #renders the data into view vars
    if (isset($data)) {
        foreach ( $data as $name => $val ) {
            $$name = $val;
        }
    }

    #require 'libraries/language/'. config('language') .'.php';
    $path = "application". DS ."views". DS . $view .".php";
    require $path;
    return TRUE;

    if ( config('compress') ) {
        while (ob_get_level() > 0) {
            ob_end_flush();
        }
    }   
}
```

again sorry, and thanks !

Comment: Do you mean, you want to wrap text automatically to fit text area width?

Comment: it should show newlines, edit my post.

Comment: does utf8 have any problem to this ? ok i think no.

Comment: Try doing "str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $string);", in case your browser's expecting both newline and carriage return, and your string has just newlines.

Comment: still dont work, i wonder why.

Comment: @Marc got any browser at hand with such behavior? If no, I still admire such "try doing". I always value good guesswork

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is very simple.

There is some your code that strips out additional newlines.
You have to investigate your code, spot the problem line and get rid of it.
Not a big deal

As a quick check you may try to print `$_POST['content']`, most likely it contains original value

Comment: maybe, im looking for it. thanks! if you are right, then i set this as an answer.

Comment: nope im getting it from the database, and yes when i do something like nl2br it works fine when i echo it outside the textarea. that above is the output from the database. wait let me do some searching a bit longer

Comment: there is no magic in web. nobody alter your data but your own code :)

Comment: Why don't you use gzip compression on the output of your views instead of physically stripping extra spaces? You could just check for the BOM and strip it out if it's there. Just check for the following characters at 0,1,2: 0xEF,0xBB,0xBF and strip them if present. (for UTF-8) Or go through with your editor and re-save without the BOM in each of your view files.

Comment: @sholshinger, is there any example ?