# What is the Newline Character for Textarea?

Tags: php, html, textarea, newline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php :: new line in textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911261/php-new-line-in-textarea)

All I need to do is skip a line in a textarea and I can't seem to to figure it out.

```
<textarea>
<?php echo $to;?>
new line character should be here
<?php echo $message?>
</textarea>
```

Everything I have read (which was a lot) has given elaborate explanations with no literal answer. Is there a character? and if yes, what is the character?

Comment: You probably need to wrap [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) around `$message`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<textarea>
<?php echo "\n" ?>
</textarea>
```

Make sure to use double quotes for `echo`.

Comment: I tried it and <br /> shows up as text.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<textarea cols="50" rows="5" id="tweet">
<?php echo "$to \n\r $message"; ?>
</textarea>
```