# New line in php mail in a loop

Tags: php

I have a variable $bijlage, which is the result of a for loop. I would like a new line for every iteration.

```
$bijlage ="";
for($x = 0; $x < count($_POST['link']); $x++) { 
    $bijlage .= $_POST['link'][$x];
}
```

`$bijlage` is part of $message

```
$message = "$aanspreking \n \n$typinleiding\n \n $opdracht\n\n$toegevoegdelinks\n\n$bijlage\n\n\n$typbegroeting";
```

Comment: Add a `\n` to the string?

Comment: Put the new line in the `for`. `foreach` would probably also be easier to use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php :: new line in textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911261/php-new-line-in-textarea)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's going to be HTML output try concatenating `<br>` with each iteration like this:

```
$bijlage .= $_POST['link'][$x] . "<br />";
```

Or, if it is just plain text, I would do either of:

```
$bijlage .= $_POST['link'][$x] . "\n";
$bijlage .= $_POST['link'][$x] . chr(10);
$bijlage .= $_POST['link'][$x] . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: thanks! It is plain text, and I had already tried adding .'\n', which didn't work. With double quotes it does!

Comment: @auurk Yea, it has to be double quotes to get it escaped. You are welcome! `:D` Have a nice day.